# Body classes in child theme

Tags: child-theme, theme-twenty-fourteen

In the theme twentyfouteen, the `full-width` class is defined with the following code

```
if ( ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) )
|| is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
 || is_attachment() ) {
 $classes[] = 'full-width';
 }
```

from this function

```
function twentyfourteen_body_classes( $classes ) {
if ( is_multi_author() ) {
    $classes[] = 'group-blog';
}

if ( get_header_image() ) {
    $classes[] = 'header-image';
} else {
    $classes[] = 'masthead-fixed';
}

if ( is_archive() || is_search() || is_home() ) {
    $classes[] = 'list-view';
}

if ( ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) )
    || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
    || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
    || is_attachment() ) {
    $classes[] = 'full-width';
}

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'footer-widgets';
}

if ( is_singular() && ! is_front_page() ) {
    $classes[] = 'singular';
}

if ( is_front_page() && 'slider' == get_theme_mod( 'featured_content_layout' ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'slider';
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    $classes[] = 'grid';
}

return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'twentyfourteen_body_classes' );
```

I'm adding a selection of sidebars to the sidebar-content.php file. These sidebars must also have the same body class as `sidebar-2`. Is it correct for me to just use a different fuction name as to that of the twentyfourteen theme and to still hook on the `body_class`, keep the same class name (full-width), and change the above code in a child theme to

```
if ( ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) &&  ! is_active_sidebar( $sidebar_option ) )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
|| is_attachment() ) {
 $classes[] = 'full-width';
 }
```

I'm getting a lot of stuff that tells me how to ad a new body class and removing one, but nothing on how to change an existing body class of a parent theme in a child theme or if it is even possible

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you creating a new function and also hooking it to `body_class`. If you don't want the parent theme's function you can also unhook that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for all the insets with this question. Here is what I come up with working from 1fixdotio's answer above. I first had to unset the full-width body class and then register a new body class to incorporate my new sidebar. Here is the code

```
  // Remove body class and register new body class to accomodate the new custom-sidebar-per-page sidebars
function remove_a_body_class($classes) {
      foreach($classes as $key => $value) {
      if ($value == 'full-width') unset($classes[$key]);
      }
return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'remove_a_body_class', 20, 2);

function pietergoosen_add_new_body_class( $classes ) {
$options = get_post_custom($post->ID);  
$sidebar_choice = $options['custom_sidebar_per_page'][0];  
    if ( (! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && ! is_active_sidebar( $sidebar_choice ) )
        || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
        || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
        || is_attachment() ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-sidebar-per-page-width';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'pietergoosen_add_new_body_class' );
```

Comment: Cool! Not sure if I still need to edit my code accordingly... But glad you figured it out by yourself. And feel free to mark your own answer as accepted, so people will skip my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say if you don't like the default `page` body class which comes with WP by default, you could do this in your filter function:

```
if ( ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) &&  ! is_active_sidebar( $sidebar_option ) )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
|| is_attachment() ) {
    if(($key = array_search( 'page', $classes)) !== false) {
        unset($classes[$key]); // Unset what you don't need
    }
    $classes[] = 'full-width'; // Add what you want
}
```

Or you could do this if you want to remove **ALL** body classes come with WP:

```
if ( ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) &&  ! is_active_sidebar( $sidebar_option ) )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
 || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
|| is_attachment() ) {
    $classes = array( 'full-width' ); // Don't use default array, set a new one
}
```

Hope I didn't get you wrong.

Comment: This is incomplete, please wrap it up with a function and add the proper hooking. just keep in mind people will find this answer from google and will not have the context the OP probably has.

Comment: Not sure if I should do as you expected. I just follow @Pieter's context, adding extra code might cause him confused. I'll let him decide if this answer would work. Anyway, thanks for your reminding.

Comment: many people copy paste code, please help them. you and me also do it from time to time.

Comment: I will paste my answer that I came up with working from 1fixdotio answer.